# Are public database subscription notifications received by all users with the same subscription?

Tags: cloudkit

I have set up a CKSubscription* so that I receive changes to a record type.

I'm using the public database.

When I test with the same user (same iCloud account) I receive the notification.

If I use a different user (different iCloud account) I don't receive the notification.

**Are subscriptions designed to only work between devices of the same user?**

Here is the documentation that describes subscriptions:

> Use a CKSubscription object to track changes occurring on the server.
>   A subscription acts like a persistent query on the server that can
>   track the creation, deletion, and modification of records. When
>   changes occur, they trigger the delivery of push notifications so that
>   your app can respond appropriately.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKSubscription_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CKSubscription

I would expect to receive a notification no matter which user edits the record, and subscription predicate should still match.

**UPDATE**

*Every user has a subscription with the same predicate, essentially focused on a single recordType with a particular property value.

The payload for this subscription is only to push shouldSendContentAvailable=YES.

The documentation reads:

> When this property is YES, the server includes the content-available
>   flag in the push notification’s payload. That flag causes the system
>   to wake or launch an app that is not currently running. The app is
>   then given background execution time to download any data related to
>   the push notification, such as the set of records that changed. **If the
>   app is already running in the foreground, the inclusion of this flag
>   has no additional effect and the notification is delivered to the app
>   delegate for processing as usual.**

The recordType's security permission is:

[image]

**FURTHER UPDATE**

Checked the logs of the device not receiving the push when it should and saw:

```
apsd[85]: Silent Push: Deny app not available
```

*Rebooted the device and now it works fine!*

Comment: Dear down-voter, what is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour was due to a mistake in how my CKSubscription was configured. If we want all users to receive notifications from the subscription then it should not have a zoneID set (should remain nil). I was setting the zoneID to the value from the defaultRecordZone, this will restrict the notifications to the current user only as the defaultRecordZone's user is the current user.

**UPDATE**

Finally solved the problem. Not only was it an issue of zoneID, but there also seems to be a bug. My subscription notificationInfo simply had shouldSendContentAvailable set to YES. This doesn't cause the subscription notification to fire for changes made by anyone other than the current user (u1d1->u1d2, but not u1d1>u2d2). I simply added an alertBody and the notifications start firing.

Anyone else face this issue?

**UPDATE 2**

Rebooting the device solved the issue.

Comment: Per the [Apple Push Notification Service ](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1) documentation the `content-available` flag causes your application to be woken up in the background, and won't alert the user. You need to have the `remote-notification` value in your application's `UIBackgroundModes` array though. If you are missing that then your application won't wake up and it will appear as if you're not getting any pushes.

Comment: Adding `alertBody` just caused the notification to come through as a regular push and alert the user, which is why you saw the notification.

Comment: Wasn't looking for user update, just wanted the app to silently update data, the background mode is set right

Comment: @farktronix - I've added all the info to the question above, let me know if you need more details.

Comment: The ID of the record zone containing the records you want to monitor. This parameter must not be nil.

Comment: I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why I was only getting notifications on devices logged in with the same user adding/updating/deleting a record. Turns out I was using `defaultRecordZone` for the subscription's zone id. Once I changed that to `nil` it started working. I wish this little detail was better documented.

Comment: The device reboot was essential in my case.  Everything worked again then.  It's almost as if, when testing or running a dev build, that the CloudKit server gets confused somehow between dev and prod notifications, requiring the reboot.  But then there is also a mention that if the user force-kills the app, a device reboot may be necessary (which is pretty bad imo).

Answer (score 3):

And to add another dimension to the answers above, CKSubscriptions are logged 'per iCloud Account' not per device.  All devices logged into the same iCloud Account (*) will receive all notifications based on any subscription entered by any device under that iCloud Account.  When the above refers to 'user' they mean 'any device logged into that iCloud Account'.

- except for the particular device that modified the file leading to the notification

Answer (score 1):

Every user should create it's own subscription. A subscription is only valid for the user that created it. On app startup you should test if the subscriptions are there for the current user (you could use the `database.fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler` function for that)

Then if there is a subscription for a recordType and predicate, then that user should receive the notifications of there are any changes for records within this recorType and predicate.

There is no guarantee that every change will be pushed. If there are multiple notifications, it could happen that you won't receive all. This is why after receiving a notification you should also query for outstanding subscription notifications on the server (using `CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation`)

If you create a record on your device, then you should not receive a notification for that on that device. So if you have a data colleciont for a subscription in your app, then you should also update this after you modified the data.

If you think this is complex, then you could try [EVCloudKitDao](https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao)

Comment: Thanks @edwin-vermeer, I understand what you've outlined here. When you say "[if] there are any changes for records within this [recordType] and predicate", does that mean no matter which user edits a record in the public database, all users who have a subscription set up will receive the change notification? Because this is the part I am not experiencing, I receive notifications fine when it's the same user on different devices, but not when it's another user on another device (that last part isn't so clear let me know if it makes sense or not).

Comment: "So if you have a data [collection] for a subscription in your app, then you should also update this after you modified the data" - not sure what this means...

Comment: lets say you query your app for recordType A and also create a subscription for recordType A. Then if you add a new record from your own phone, then you won't get a notification. so the newly created record will be missing from the results of the initial query. If you still have that results in memory, then you should also update that result.

Comment: Ok, my problem isn't related to the current user not receiving a notification for a record he saves. My problem is having two separate users who have the same subscription to the same record type, but the notification is not posting for userB when userA saves a record, BUT, userA on another device gets the notification.

Comment: Ok - I think my issue is that I'm not setting zoneID to nil. I'm trying to set it to the default zoneID for a public database, which could be the issue. I will try tonight and close this question if that's the case, thanks in any case Edwin, appreciate the help.

Comment: Related to the comment above, I'm using defaultRecordZone rather than nil, this makes sense, as the default record zone restricts the scope to the current user. "The owner of the zone is set to CKOwnerDefaultName, which corresponds to the current user." https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKRecordZone_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CKRecordZone/defaultRecordZone